# Create table and columns from CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, csv, import

Is there a Ruby gem which reads in a CSV file and then creates a table based on its guess of the data types of each column? I believe you can do this in Python with the pandas function `to_sql`, but I'm having difficulty finding a Ruby gem. I am using Postgres if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can import CSV directly in postgresql

Comment: @Gearnode without the table existing?

Comment: you must create table before, and after just import your csv in postgresql. But you can create an SQL function for create table with column from your CSV.

Comment: My question states that I want something that automatically guesses the data types to create the table for me. I'm aware that you can import CSV data into Postgres if the table already exists.